# Is there a way to change queue consuming order of Celery + RabbitMQ?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

- `celery 5.0.5`
- `Python 3.8`
- `RabbitMQ 3.8`

I have a worker subscribing to 2 queues: `Q1` and `Q2` like this: `celery -A app worker -Q Q1,Q2`.

Is there a way to tell the worker only consumes from `Q1` until the queue is empty, and then consumes from `Q2`. In other words, consuming from `Q1` should be prioritized over consuming from `Q2`.